# Copy Options Goes Up in EditText

Tags: android, copy, android-edittext

I have a Transparent Activity and On It is an Edit Text When Its Full and I Select piece of Text in Bottom of Text Copy Options Goes Up.
How I Prevent This?

[image: Screenshot of Copy Options Hiding]